# Avoid the repetitive calling of the same method

Tags: java

I am working on a project for my Intro to Java course. I submitted my code and the reviewer said I needed to rewrite the following:

```
public void move()
   {
   if (iCanWin() > -1)
   {
       moveOnColumn(iCanWin()); 
   }
   else if (theyCanWin(0, 0, false) > -1)
   {
        moveOnColumn(theyCanWin(0, 0, false)); 
    else
   {
        moveOnColumn(brilliantMove()); 
   }
 }



int nextMove = iCanWin();
if(nextMove > -1) {
 moveOnColumn(nextMove);
} else ...
```

Not sure what should come after the else... The reviewer said that this would avoid the repetitive calling of the same method.

Comment: Can you move your post to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You're on the right track.  Rewrite your `if` statement, but assign values to `nextMove` instead of calling `moveOnColumn` on them.  Then, at the end, `moveOnColumn(nextMove)`.

Comment: Thank you ajb. That makes sense. I did that and it worked.

Comment: You feel free to accept my answer if you wont

Answer (score 0):

generally in statement if-ifelse-else

```
  if (check a condition is true?)
 {
   moveOnColumn(iCanWin()); //do something
 }
 else if (other condition is true?) 
 {
    moveOnColumn(theyCanWin(0, 0, false)); //do something
  else//otherwise
  {
    moveOnColumn(brilliantMove());  //if previous condition doesn't be true
  almost one of them this line go to be execute
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. It makes total sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the repetitive calls where possible as @ajb mentioned

```
public void move(){
    int nextMove = iCanWin();
    if (nextMove <= -1){
        nextMove = theyCanWin(0, 0, false);
        if(nextMove <= -1){
            nextMove = brilliantMove();
        }
    }
    moveOnColumn(nextMove); 
}
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you. This is what I did.

Comment: int nextMove = iCanWin();
       if (nextMove > -1)
       {
           moveOnColumn(nextMove);       }
       else 
       {
           nextMove = theyCanWin(0, 0, false);  // If I am not sure I can win
           if (nextMove > -1)
           {
             moveOnColumn (brilliantMove()); // If neither one of us can win, then a brilliant move is made
           }
       }

Comment: @TSgtKPF could you please, mark one of the answers as accepted as you said they answer your question